# Better binding to prevent broken `this` reference when setting prototype method on Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor like this:

```
/** @constructor */
function MyClass() {

}

var globalInstance = new MyClass();
```

Then, I need to provide an implementation for a method for `MyClass` instances. This can vary by context, so I have calls like this in another context:

```
function OtherConstructor() {
    MyClass.prototype.methodName = function() {
        localFunction(this);
    }
}
```

I need to reference the `MyClass` instance `this` from inside the method. However, when another object calls `globalInstance.methodName` from something like `setTimeout`, `this` gets disconnected.

Is there a better way to bind `this` such that it cannot be clobbered later? I considered [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which did not result in dynamic binding of `this` but also does not keep `this` bound to my `MyClass` instance but instead to the `OtherConstructor` instance. My current solution is to use `bind` and `apply` like so:

```
function doSomethingAfterDelay(delay) {
    setTimeout(globalInstance.methodName.bind(globalInstance), delay);
}

function doThingsAfterDelay(delay) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        doSomething();
        globalInstance.methodName.call(globalInstance);
    }, delay);
}
```

But, I would like to avoid having to remember the implementation detail and preserve the `this` binding in a central location if possible. Some ES6 features are on the table as long as they are available in the latest versions of Safari, Chrome, Opera, Edge, and Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: `globalInstance.methodName()` should work fine.  You don't need to use `.call()`.

Comment: Remember, that `this` is set based on how the function is *called*, not now its declared.  Also remember that functions can be treated like variables.  So, when you use `setTimeout` you are passing it the function itself (the function doesn't know that it's part of `globalInstance`).

Comment: How your constructors are set up doesn't have anything to do with the problem you're describing. It's just a fact of JS that unless an object is bound as the `this` value of a function, you'll lose the `this` value you desire if you sever the relationship between the call of the function and that object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat When using `setTimeout`, the `this` context is broken. So if I call `globalInstance.methodName()` its reference to `this` inside of it is not to the `globalInstance` object but to the global `Window` object. So far, `call` or `bind` is the best alternative I have found. I'm perfectly willing to have "not possible" be the answer, but I wanted to ask and see if there was some trick I wasn't aware of to make it happen.

Comment: @jxpx777: `setTimeout(globalInstance.methodName, delay)` is not the same as `setTimeout(function(){ globalInstance.methodName(); }, delay)`.  Though, if what you have works, then it's probably fine.

Comment: Ah, I see, @RocketHazmat! Yes, you're right that the `call` version is a step more than is needed. Thanks!